# How to plot count of genres from a column, and not counting (Drama, Action) differently than (Drama) [img included]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

A known IMDb data frame for movies, in the genres columns, the movie could have:
"Drama, Adventure, Romance", and another movie could just have "Drama"

I want to plot what is the highest count for each "genre" instead of counting
"Drama" and "Drama, adventure" as two separate genres.

I used this to count the year with the most year count.

```
sns.countplot(y="g", data=genre_list, palette="Set2", order=df['genre'].value_counts().index[0:15])
```

When I do the same with the genres, obviously it doesn't work, here's how it is showing for me. I know I need a workaround for it, maybe doing a loop and splitting, but I think there's an easier way.

[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution, this is the code I used.

```
df = df.assign(genres=df.genre.str.split(", ")).explode('genres')
```

We did a string (str) split by the "," between each value and assign it to new
variable "genres". Then I used "explode" to add each value in "genres" in a new row. Lastly, "assign" to add it to the original dataframe.

Hope this helps anyone in the future.